# grant_type password requires client_id to be set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I'm setting up an asp.net core 2 web api using IdentityServer4 and I need to support Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant due to some existing customers. I'm having an issue with getting the token because it says "No client identifier found".

This fails...

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
grant_type=password&username=myuser&password=mypassword
```

This succeeds...

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
grant_type=password&username=myuser&password=mypassword&client_id=ro.client
```

Why do I need to add client_id for this to work? The OAuth 2.0 spec doesn't specify needing it - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client
> credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the
> client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described
> in Section 3.2.1. - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3

The request involves a client impersonating a user, and IdentityServer always needs to know what client is making the request, so that it can authorize it (e.g. validate the requested scopes, maybe even authenticate it).

I'm with IdentityServer here. I don't know of any scenario where I would want public access to for the ROPC grant type. Do you?

Also, please don't use the ROPC grant type, it's 2018 dude: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Comment: HA! 2018...I wish I could use that excuse. Our customers had a hard enough time switching to cable internet instead of using dialup...Do I want public access to the ROPC grant type? No, but we don't have public APIs so our business is a little different. As for my question, the OAuth 2 spec does say that the client must authenticate, but there's nothing in the spec saying the client_id is require when sending a ROPC request. So, is this just an IdentityServer4 requirement?

Comment: To authenticate, the client needs to identify itself. Even if you're not providing a secret, it would need to implicitly authenticate itself. Thinking about it, unless you're allowing public access to the ROPC grant, you'll always need some sort of client authentication. But sure, it's a IdentityServer requirement.

Comment: Im with @DanH on this one :) Trying to port an old owin app to dotnetcore, and the old clients DONT send client_id, so now I have to update the clients as well...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what OWIN libraries are doing that? I know the MS Katana libraries include client_id (at least the OpenID Connect ones do), does the pure OAuth one not?